# clustering,affinity propagation algorithm, minimal number of elements in one cluster

Tags: clustering

Could someone please clarify the following:

I applied the Affinity Propagation (AP) algorithm to a dataset. The minimum number of elements in one cluster I got was three. I knew in advance that my dataset would contain some unique elements that should be allocated to a separate, alone cluster. So, I would like to set the minimum number of elements in any cluster to one and apply AP. Is it possible to do this in relation to AP (change some parameters), or is it a property of AP to do clustering such that each cluster has at least three elements?

Answer (score 0):

Such answers are best answered if you would read the *original* publication of affinity propagation, and study the source code, rather than relying on some vague information from an online QA site...

It's fairly easy to see that AP does not ensure a minimum cluster size. Your control over cluster sizes is only indirect, based on a "self-responsibility" of each point.

Answer (score 0):

You can't decide the minimal number of items in a cluster in the original AP algorithm. Here's a simpler derivation of it by the original authors:

https://www.psi.toronto.edu/pubs2/2009/NC09%20-%20SimpleAP.pdf

AP is essentially a max-sum, factor graph based algorithm. It maximises a negative similarity given the following 2 constraints:

1. There can be only 1 exemplar chosen per item.
2. An item can only choose an exemplar if it chooses itself.

There is nothing constraining the number of points that choose an exemplar however the paper above does detail how you might change the algorithm to do exactly that. I have not seen an implementation of it, but I have implemented AP myself, and it is pretty easy. You can get the matlab code from the authors website.

Finally, if you want to put a specific set of points into a cluster together, that can be done by making them very close together in your similarity matrix.